# How to generate interface with default property with nswag?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-codegen, nswag

Is this possible to generate typescript interface with nswag that will contain the default property value?

i.e. from this:

```
public enum TempType
{
    Good = 1,
    Bad = 2
}

public class Item
{
    [DefaultValue(TempType.Good)] public TempType TempType { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get interface like this in the generated code:

```
export interface Item {
    tempType?: TempType.Good;
}
```

In other words I want to generate code that contains enum member types generated from c# classes: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types

Comment: There is [this VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.csharp-to-typescript) but I don't know if it handle default value like that.

Comment: Well, there is no default value for interfaces in typescript. The above example is not a default value but instead a type. You can not assign `tempType` property to a value other than `TempType.Good`. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1B1N)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using the [DefaultValue] attribute in order to specify the default value for a property, and then use the NSwag tool to generate TypeScript interface.

So, you would start where you did and have the enum and class, then apply the default value attribute.

```
public enum TempType
{
    Good = 1,
    Bad = 2
}

public class Item
{
    [DefaultValue(TempType.Good)] public TempType TempType { get; set; }
}
```

Then, if not already you would install NSwag command line tool.

```
dotnet tool install NSwag.Console -g
```

Then, use the NSwag tool to generate a TypeScript interface from your C# code. So,

```
nswag run path/to/your/project.csproj -p:GenerateDefaultValues=true -c:TypeScript
```

After running the command, NSwag will generate a TypeScript interface like the one you seek for your C# class that includes default property values

Also, note that the property tempType is marked as optional, since it's possible for the property to have a null.